# Python two-dimensional list: exporting as delimited text file

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I have a 2-D list, myList[r][c], where there are `r` rows of `c` columns each.

I am trying to export it into a text file, with each of the column elements delimited by pipes | , and an ampersand & at the end of each row.

```
myList = [[[] for a in range(c)] for b in range(r)]

{a bunch of code populating  myList}

f = open("myfile.txt","w")
for x in range(0,r):
    thisRow = ''
     for y in range(0,c):
          appendThis = myList[x][y]
          thisRow += appendThis + "|"
     f.write(thisRow)
     f.write("&")
f.close
```

...but I get `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list` on the line where I add the pipe character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `csv` module is made for this.  Python 2.7 example:

```
import csv
r=7
c=5
myList = [[b*10+a for a in range(c)] for b in range(r)]

with open("myfile.txt","wb") as f:
    w = csv.writer(f,delimiter='|',lineterminator='&\r\n')
    w.writerows(myList)
```

Output:

```
0|1|2|3|4&
10|11|12|13|14&
20|21|22|23|24&
30|31|32|33|34&
40|41|42|43|44&
50|51|52|53|54&
60|61|62|63|64&
```

Answer (score 2):

Python has great support for CSV. The following is adapted straight from an [example](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html):

```
import csv
with open('myfile.txt', 'wb') as csvfile:
    mywriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='|',lineterminator='&',
                            quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    mywriter.writerow(myList)
```

note the use of the `lineterminator` if you want each line to have an `&` at the end as well as a new line you can use '&\r\n' as the terminator.

In case I have got your rows and columns mixedup, please note that you can do something like

```
for line in myList:
    mywriter.writerow(line)
```

Answer (score 2):

So here you have a working version.
The problem was in the first line, where you had:

```
myList = [[[] for a in range(c)] for b in range(r)]
```

but that just creates 2-D array of arrays, I have replaced it with an array that simply contains the indexes of its elements. (And also now it adds newlines to the line ends.)

```
myList = [[a for a in range(c)] for b in range(r)]


f = open("myfile.txt","w")
for x in range(0,r):
    thisRow = ''
    for y in range(0,c):
      appendThis = myList[x][y]
      thisRow += str(appendThis) + "|"
    f.write(thisRow)
    f.write("&\n")
f.close
```